# how do I parse chunks in a byte array

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core, packet

So I have this big buffer in the shape of a byte array that I get from the client and I receive it on the server and it looks like this.

```
[10, 0, 5, 11, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 133, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 134, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 136, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 137, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 140, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 148, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 153, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 154, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 155, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 156, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 157, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 160, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 162, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 163, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 164, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 166, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 169, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 170, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 171, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 172, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 173, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 175, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 176, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 179, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 185, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 189, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 190, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 193, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 194, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 195, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 196, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 197, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 198, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 201, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 203, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 205, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 206, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 207, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 208, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 209, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 210, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 211, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 213, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 214, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 216, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 217, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 218, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 11, 219, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6]
```

And there is a pattern to this.
It's a buffer filled with a few packets and the packets look like this.

The first two bytes are reserved for the size (int16) `[10, 0]`

Then there is the next byte which is the type of the packet (5) `[10, 0, 5]`

and then the rest is the payload `[10, 0, 5, 11, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

And the goal here is that I want to read the length of the packet - the length so just the payload, process it and then read the next packet which is the length of the next packet.

The only way I can think of is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //ProcessBuffer();
}
```

But that only does it for the first 10, it doesnt change that `10` to what the length of the next one is.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: So why not read the length, do processing, change the index to that length until you've hit the end of the byte array?

Comment: @RossJacobs What do you mean? I'm not quite following

Comment: Use a while loop with an index to get the first length of packet, add the packet to a packet list, and then increase the index by the packet length. Do this until the index >= the number of bytes in this byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `buffer` contains the `Byte[]`:

```
var bufferPos = 0;

do {
    // get size of next packet
    var packetSize = buffer[bufferPos]+buffer[bufferPos+1]*256;
    // get type of next packet
    var packetType = buffer[bufferPos+2];
    var payload = new ArraySegment<Byte>(buffer, bufferPos+3, packetSize-3);
    // process packet here

    bufferPos += packetSize;
} while (bufferPos < buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense! I really like the way you utilized a do while loop!

Comment: Do/while ignores the edge case of having an empty input array (let's pretend you capture packets on the wrong interface or with too strict a filter). Given this question, that's probably fine though. OP knows more about his requirements than we do.

Comment: @RossJacobs Good point - I did assume the buffer wasn't empty by the time it is being parsed, but a `while` might be better after all.